# Why isn't EIP3009 getting much use?

Tags: ecrecover, eip, eip712

I am researching the use of the EIP3009 and am noticing that the proposal, though implemented in, say, USDC's smart contracts, is not actually getting used (the functions have never been called in USDC's smart contract.) I have a working theory as to why this is the case, but am not sure if I am correct.
It seems like EIP3009 aims to solve for scalability and for the allowance front running attacks, and was supposed to be an improvement on Uniswap's EIP2612. It requires some sort of relayer to listen for the signed messages. I am unsure of whether or not ECRecover contract scheme mitigates the need for a centralized relayer.
That being said, with ZKRollups and sharding becoming increasingly popular, EIP3009 has lost its edge as the aforementioned solutions are more robust.

Is the connection between EIP3009 and sharding/ZKRollup alternatives correct? Is this why EIP3009 has basically become dormant?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

the eip-3009 can be complicated, took me (too) long.
i tested first with a stub contract with hardhat and the referenced eip-3009 repo example.

"--> error  invalid signature"

Very easy to make errors in various places.

I think the example in the eip3009 has a wrong order here:
EIP712.sol, line 60
address(this),
bytes32(chainId)

newer USDC contracts seem to have changed that ( i looked on OP e.g. )

Answer (score 0):

Because of

- Legacy
- Inertia
- Miseducation: ERC-20 is the only true token standard
- Stagnation of Ethereum ecosystem in general

It is unlikely the Ethereum ecosystem can long term, or ever, crawl out from the pit of ERC-20 standard and its failures because it has not happened in 6 years and there is no community sentiment or excitement to get it to happen. It is more likely that other non-EVM blockchain L1s innovate in token standard area and take over Ethereum over long term with better UX.